# Returning the key in a c# dictionary who's value(class) meets a criteria

Tags: c#, dictionary, priority-queue

Given the following code, what is the best way to return the key with the lowest age from the dictionary.

```
 public class Person
    {
        public int age {get; set;}
        public string name {get; set;}

        public Person(int Age, string Name)
        {
            age = Age;
            name = Name;
        }
    }


    public Dictionary<int, Person> people = new Dictionary<int, Person>();

    public int idNumber = // Key of person with lowest age inside Dictionary ?????
```

I've looked into priority queues, but it all seems to overkill.  I feel like there must be a simple way to just say give me the key where age is the lowest.

Comment: A Dictionary can find a Value from a Key. That's what it does. Use a different ADT to deal with ordered Values. Of course the `Dictioanry<K,V>` can be treated as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` and the standard LINQ (eg. `OrderBy`) applies - but this is not utilizing the nature of the Dictionary (or of a different ADT), and such might result in less-than-ideal asymmetric bounds depending on how it is used.

Comment: What about : people.OrderBy(val=>val.Value).Select(t=>t.Key).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I think Lookup class would be better for this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could find the lowest age, then find the person with that age (or the first person with that age, there could be multiples):

```
int lowestAge = people.Min(kvp => kvp.Value.age);
int id = people.First(kvp => kvp.Value.age == lowestAge).Key;
```

or, even simpler, just use `OrderBy` and grab the first:

```
int id = people.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.age).First().Key;
```

Comment: First sample would most likely to be faster.

Answer (score 5):

```
var key = people.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Value.age < b.Value.age ? a : b).Key;
```

Comment: Clever. Avoids double-scanning but also avoids a manually-typed foreach.